# BroadcastReceiver not receiving when .addAction() is pressed

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to dismiss a notification from an `.addAction()` without having to open the app. The problem is when the button is pressed nothing happens, the `onReceive()` method doesn't trigger.

Here is the code on the MainActivity:

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("id", SOMENUMBER);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
    notification.setContentTitle("");
    notification.setContentText(t);
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notification.setOngoing(true);
    notification.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Dismiss", pIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(SOMENUMBER, notification.build());
```

And on other class I have the reciever:

```
public class Notification extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(intent.getIntExtra("id", 0));
    }
}
```

And the reciever on the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<receiver android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="io.github.seik.Notification" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Does `MainActivity` extend `Activity` or `BroadcastReceiver`? Your naming convention is confusing :-(

Comment: @DavidWasser No, only the Notification class extends BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your naming conventions are confusing. Android already has a class called `Notification`, so you probably shouldn't call your receiver `Notification` :-(

If `MainActivity` extends `Activity` then you need to have a manifest entry for it that looks like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
```

For your `BroadcastReceiver`, you need a manifest entry like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".Notification"
    android:exported="true"/>
```

Since you are using an explicit `Intent` to launch your `BroadcastReceiver`, you don't need to provide an `<intent-filter>` for it. Since the `BroadcastReceiver` will be started by the `NotificationManager`, you need to make sure that it is `exported`.

You then need to create the `PendingIntent` so that it actually launches your `BroadcastReceiver`, so change this:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
```

to this:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext, Notification.class);
```